# How to get the list of values during Prolog backtracking?

Tags: prolog, backtracking

Say I have the following piece of code:

```
edge(a, b).
edge(a, c).
edge(a, d).
```

Now when I do

```
neighbors(V, N) :- edge(V, N), writeln(N), fail.
```

I can get a list of the neighbors printed out to the console. But how can I get it as a result list? Something like

```
neighbors(V, Vs)  :- 
    edge(V, N),
    not(member(N, Vs)),
    neighbors(V, [N|Vs]).
```

(the above piece doesn't really work due to the way `member` is handled. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bagof/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof%2F3) to create a list of your verticies that satisfy the goal, "Vs is all N that is an edge of V."

```
neighbors(V, Vs) :- bagof(N, edge(V, N), Vs).

neighbors(a, Vs). % Vs = [b, c, d].
```

Answer (score 3):

Read about `findall`, `bagof` and `setof` in your favorite Prolog implementation's manual, or e.g. the section "11.2 Collecting solutions" in [Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.learnprolognow.org/)
(Unfortunately it is difficult to directly link to these resources.)